FFmpeg filter use other streams characteristics
I have a workflow in which I have a ffmpeg command with several images and a video as input
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 50 -t 4.0 -i img1.png -loop 1 -r 50 -t 1.0 -i img2.png -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -r 50 -i img3.png ...

I perform a few operations on the inputs, and at the end I concatenate everything together using the concat filter.
For the moment, I'm doing this for horizontal videos only (1920x1080), and now I want to be able to do it for vertical video inputs (1080x1920). The problem is that the images I'm going to use will always be horizontal, only the input video will be vertical. So I have to scale the images in 1080x1920 to be able to concatenate them.
It works when I test it hard-coded, but I can't find a way to make my command "hybrid", so it works with both vertical and horizontal.
The only way to determine if I must output an horizontal or vertical video is the input video, so I thought of something like this do determine what scaling I'm going to apply to the images:
[0:v]scale='if(lt(in_w,in_h),1080,1920)':'if(lt(in_w,in_h),1920,1080)'[v0]

In this filter, in_w and in_h refer to the image's input width and height, but I'd like to use the width and height from the video. So is it possible to use the video dimensions in an other stream ?
Thank you

This is what the scale2ref filter is for.
